# C#: Better way to override an abstract method in which the overridden method ignores some of its arguments

Tags: c#, arguments, abstract-class, overriding

So, I have an abstract class with a method with 3 parameters, which is overridden in a particular base class.

The abstract method is in the following form:

```
internal override void SummonJonSkeet(string dumbQuestion, int a, int b)
{
    // Call upon Jon Skeet and his followers to correct my ignorant ways. 
}
```

In most of the subclasses that implement the given method, all 3 parameters are needed to produce a correct result. However, in this particular instance the only valid values of a and b are 0.

Currently what I am doing is just ignoring their values within the method, and providing a warning in the documentation comment for the method, but this just feels...wrong.

There has to be a better way than forcing a programmer (well, me) to insert junk arguments into the method call just to make the compiler happy, while still requiring the use of these arguments for every other subclass that implements the method.

Maybe this is a dumb question, since my solution works, but it just feels like it's not a smart way to do it. For example, some idiot (probably me) shouldn't be able to come along and cause an unhandled exception by inserting some ridiculous number into an argument that isn't used in the first place.

Comment: _"the only valid values of a and b are 0"_ -- if the only valid values are `0`, why do you ignore the values? Should instead you be validating them and throwing an exception if the caller passes invalid values? Alternatively, if you have an abstract method where not all of the parameters are always used, are you sure you really have the right design? Of course, no one can comment on your design, because you haven't shared any specifics. There are certainly lots of ways around the basic issue, but your question is so non-specific, it's not possible to know what answer is right for you.

Comment: a and b are actually x and y coordinates. The method inserts something into this coordinate system. In this particular subclass, the they should only be able to insert at [0,0]. Validating the values is an option, but it feels like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: _"Validating the values is an option, but it feels like the wrong way to do it"_ -- why does it feel wrong? Do you really want a caller passing non-zero values, and then being confused as to why those values seemed to have no effect? Like I said, it seems more likely to me that the broader design is flawed, but we don't have the opportunity to comment on that. Given the design you seem to have settled on, it seems to me you should require the caller to provide correct and valid values.

Comment: @Peter No, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Having to pass meaningless values that do nothing. I was hoping C# had some kind of feature that allowed things like this that I just didn't know about, but perhaps not. What would you say about the way I am currently doing it? (Allowing the caller to pass any int and warning them in the documentation that it does nothing.)

Comment: _"Having to pass meaningless values that do nothing"_ -- unless you change your design, you're stuck with that. If you want to avoid that, fix the design. Don't make a bad problem worse by also making it hard to understand how the method is called _"What would you say about the way I am currently doing it?"_ -- I think you already know the answer to that question. I think your current implementation is wrong; you should validate the input and make sure the caller passes `0` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (given that you mentioned the parameters are really coordinates that may or may not be used) could be just to make the values nullable with default values of null.

```
internal override void SummonJonSkeet(string dumbQuestion, int? a = null, int? b = null)
```

You'd have to match the abstract definition as well, but this shows the approach.

This allows the sub-classes to call `SummonJonSkeet("my question")` or `SummonJonSkeet("my question", 1, 2)` based on its implementation. The sub-classes that expect the values can then check `a.HasValue` or `a != null` to throw errors when values does not exist for parameters when expected to have values. To get the primitive value, just call `a.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an approach that creates a class for the parameters (assuming you might need these parameters to have specific names or various types).

```
public class BasicQuestionParameters { public string DumbQuestion {get;set;} }
```

Then, you could modify your abstract class to be generic that requires a type that is of the type BasicQuestionParameters.

```
public abstract class SummonBase<TParams> where TParams : BasicQuestionParameters
{
     abstract void SummonJobSkeet(TParams question);
}
```

Now you can implement your sub-classes to define what type of question parameters it needs as long as they start from your basic one.

```
public class MySummonBasic : SummonBase<BasicQuestionParameters>
{
    internal override void SummonJonSkeet(BasicQuestionParameters question) {...}
}
```

The benefit here is now you can add additional parameters by inheritance:

```
public class HardQuestionParameters : BasicQuestionParameters
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public int B {get;set;}
}
```

And then use this in only the sub-classes that need the more refined type:

```
public class HardSummon : SummonBase<HardQuestionParameters>
{
     internal override void SummonJonSkeet(HardQuestionParameters question) {...}
}
```

Now each sub-class has exactly the parameters it needs and nothing more or less. This approach has the added benefit that if you find a set of sub-classes need an additional parameter (C), you can do it by only needing to update the sub-classes that need to use the additional parameter. No need to touch all the other sub-classes that just need the basic parameters.

Comment: If you do this, you lose the benefit of being able to store something as a `SummonBase`, however, as you will need to know the type of parameters it takes.

Comment: I left a comment on Peter's answer that explains that a and b are actually x and y coordinates, so I will never need more than these two (guess I should have been more clear on that) so adding an entire class for these two parameters seems like overkill. Is there another way I could do this? This seems like a good way to do it if each class needed a different set of parameters, but this is one particular instance in which 2 of them should be optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the int parameters, you can change the signature of the virtual method to:

```
internal override void SummonJonSkeet(string dumbQuestion, params int[] values)
{
    //...
}
```

In this way you can call it with only the string parameter, like this:

```
this.SummonJonSkeet(dumbQuestion);
```

Comment: The problem is that just a string parameter is NEVER a valid input except for in this particular subclass. It seems like this solution would be trading one danger area for several.

Comment: Do you have the same logic for the classes where only 0  is valid value for a and b? If so, you can use default values for a and b in the base signature and call with base in inheritants.Some more code will shed more light and help answer this.

Comment: The logic is not the same, but very similar. I think you are on to something here.

Comment: Actually, i am just guessing. Can do nothing else without more code.